# Use URL varibles in other php file

Tags: php

I am working on using URL values passed to another php file. However, every time I try to use the value of name variable conjunction with the ordinary variable below, PHP won't read it!

```
global $counterforlist;
 $counterforlist= 0;
echo "<form method=\"POST\"  action=\" ".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."\" > ";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>ID:</td><td>Company Name</td><td>Date for Service</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counterforlist = $counterforlist +1;
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber$counterforlist' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"   ; 
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany$counterforlist' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>" ;
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'dateforService$counterforlist' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"   ;
echo "<td><a href=\"update_request.php?jobrequestnumber{$counterforlist}={$row['jobrequestnumber']}&requestingcompany{$counterforlist}={$row['requestingcompany']}&dateforService{$counterforlist}={$row['dateforService']}&{$counterforlist}={$counterforlist}\">Update</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?jobrequestnumber=".$row['jobrequestnumber']."'>Delete</a></td>"; //too
echo "</tr>";
<?php include('update_request.php');?>
```

---

This is the other php file calling those values
in update_request:

```
<?php 
global $counterforlist;

$jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"."$counterforlist"];
$requestingcompany=$_GET["requestingcompany"."$counterforlist"];
$dateforService=$_GET["dateforService"."$counterforlist"]; 

$required_array=array($jobrequestnumber,$requestingcompany,$dateforService);
$errors = array();
$errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_array, $_POST));
if (empty($errors)){
// Database submission only proceeds if there were NO errors.
    $query =    "UPDATE jobrequest SET 
                        requestingcompany = '{$requestingcompany}',
                        dateforService = {$dateforService} 
                    WHERE jobrequestnumber ={$jobrequestnumber}";
                    echo $jobrequestnumber;
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

---

Error messages:

> Notice: Undefined index: jobrequestnumber in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: requestingcompany in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: dateforService in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 9

---

If I were to declare variables again, it won't read values from previous php page.
Can you help me figure out what I have been missing?

Comment: Probably need to pass it as a variable more like OOP methods using functions and parameters. I believe the $_POST / $_GET variables have a scope of only the page that they're posted to.

Comment: Not possible, but real duplicate question. Close and delete this

Comment: It is for URL varible not name varibles so, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and? your other PHP file does not have `$counterforlist` defined, so something like

```
$jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"."$counterforlist"];
```

is seen as

```
$jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"];
```

since you're sending in `jobrequestnumber1`, `jobrequestnumber2`, etc... a simple plain `jobrequestnumber` is not going to exist.

`global` in PHP does not make a variable persist across multiple DIFFERENT scripts. and unless you're using that declaration inside a `function()` definition, will not much at all anyways.

You probably want something like this:

```
$jobrequests = preg_grep('/^jobrequestnumber\d+$/', array_keys($_GET)); // get matching key names
foreach($jobrequests as $jobrequest) {
   $key = substr($jobrequest, 12); // extract the digit(s) from the end of the key name
   ...
}
```

Comment: cud you pls share me a link for  his part preg_grep('/^jobrequestnumber\d+$/', array_keys($_GET)); ?

Comment: http://php.net/preg_grep http://php.net/array_keys